# How to split JavaDStream<String> and print the second word of the line

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

after i split the line I can only print all the word, but in my case i want only the second word of the line how can i solve it?

```
JavaDStream<String> words = kafkaSparkInputDStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
                    return Arrays.asList(x.split(" "));
                }
            });
words.print();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you just select which element's you want from splited array ? You can use
`x.split(1)[1]` but that one might result in exception's so another way of doing so which is more error prone is:

```
JavaDStream<String> words = kafkaSparkInputDStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
                    return Arrays.stream(x.split(" "))
                        .skip(1)
                        .limit(1)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                }
            });
words.print();
```